# Cost for some Instance flavors are missing in AzureRM Rate Card API

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

When I try to get cost using ratecard API using the following API URL

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subsid>/providers/Microsoft.Commerce/RateCard?api-version=2015-05-15&$filter=OfferDurableId eq 'MS-AZR-0003P' and Currency eq 'USD' and Locale eq 'en-US' and RegionInfo eq 'US'
```

I dont get some flavor/tier instance prices like Standard_DS13_v2.

Also I was unable to find DS-series, DSv2-series, GS-series, Ls-series, Fs-series and Esv3-series too.

How do I get cost for those type of Flavors ?

Comment: It seems a api-version issue. I test in my lab, I also could not get S series VM.

Comment: But I use the latest version(2016-08-31-preview), I also could not get S series VM.

Comment: Anyway to solve this ?

Comment: Currently, it is not possible except Azure update this api. I even check Meter ID from this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/meter-rename/), S series VM is also not in the list.

Comment: So how do I get the prices for those resources ?

Comment: any workaround or something ?

Comment: If you really need this, I suggest you could ask a ticket to Azure or use Azure Pricing calculator https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166726/discussion-between-arun-kumar-g-r-and-shengbao-shui-msft).